# Error when building dataset for chainer model manually

Tags: neural-network, dataset, chainer

There is an error when I train an NN with manual dataset. My code is [here](https://github.com/cmjdxy/practice-chainer/blob/master/train_with_manual_data.py). Run *python train_with_manual_data.py --manual 1*, the output error is:

```
InvalidType: 
Invalid operation is performed in: SoftmaxCrossEntropy (Forward)

Expect: in_types[1].dtype.kind == i
Actual: u != i
```

But run *python train_with_manual_data.py --manual 0*, there will be no problem. I don't know why, anyone get a clue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of the error message is: [dtype kind](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html) of argument #1 (0-origin, i.e., label) for [softmax_cross_entropy function](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.functions.softmax_cross_entropy.html) is expected to be `i` (signed integer), but `u` (unsigned integer) is given.
Try casting it, e.g., `mnist.train.labels.astype(numpy.int32)`.